# Customizing the SharePoint 2010 Blog Template

Tags: templates, sharepoint-2010, blogs, branding, customizing

I want to apply branding to a sharepoint 2010 blog site which is a sub site of our internet. I'm trying to achieve this by creating a custom blog site template based on the original blog site template. So I followed the following blog post.

http://www.sharepointbits.com/blog/sharepoint-2010-custom-site-templates.html

And I got a copy of the blog template files from "C:...\14\TEMPLATE\SiteTemplates\blog", modified the files and put in to the "SiteTemplates\" folder.

I can see a new site template has been created but every time when I create a web site based on my custom template it uses the original blog template files for provisioning (for ex: default.aspx).

Is this the correct way to achieve this? Please let me know if I'm doing sth wrong here.

Thanks in advance.

-Madhawa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you created a custom webtemp file in 14\TEMPLATE\1033\XML that has a custom Template Name with a SetupPath that points to your copied folder in SiteTemplates?

Also, the Blog site definition is tricky. The custom lists are built right into the onet.xml file. I wonder if creating a custom copy of the Blog template will work as well as copying other site types would. I would probably use feature stapling to apply custom branding to the out of the box Blog template within your site collection.

Comment: Hay Rich, Thanks for the reply. I haven't created the webtemp XML file in 14/TEMPLATE/1033/XML folder. Anyway I wanna do this in the best possible way and gonna try feature stapling.

Thanks again.